# Alertpay payment: how come customers can change shipping address in the end?

Tags: ecommerce

I've the following issue with the payment service Alertpay.com

I've a drupal-based website, and I forward customers to Alertpay to insert their credit card information.

The issue is that Alertpay offers an option to change shipping address. I really don't like this, because each country has a different shipping rate (included in the total I pass to Alertpay).

Consequently a customer could set a country in my website, pay a low shipping rate, and then change the shipping address in Alert Pay without updating the shipping costs.

ps. There is also a field shipping_costs in AlertPay parameters, but still Alertpay provides an option to change shipping country. I don't get why, it is not logical.

thanks

Comment: I'd ask AlertPay, but this seems like a Good reason to use a real payment gateway like Authorize.net or similar.

Comment: @Lèse majesté Isn't an amazing problem if this would be true ? I'm waiting for their answer... authorize.net is not available in europe unfortunately, like paypal payment pro..

Comment: It definitely seems poorly thought out. And I know Authorize.net is unavailable in Europe, but I'm sure there is some kind of similar payment gateway that European e-commerce sites use--one that doesn't take customers off your website to make the payment. Those services give you much more control, preventing this sort of problem from ever arising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the address but not the country on AlertPay's checkout page. If you have already captured your customer's information and stored it in a database, then you should ignore the shipping address that is returned from the IPN since you would only need to validate that the payment was done properly and then simply pull the shipping info from your database. This will avoid the scenario that you have described.

For any further concerns or inquiry, I would invite you to ask your questions on our Developers' Forum at dev.alertpay.com

Comment: That might work, but I'd be concerned with customers who put in the wrong shipping info on his site and used the second address form to change it. Most would assume that the store will use the last shipping address they put in, and this could result in costly problems.

Comment: @AP Dev This is what I'm doing indeed, and @Lèse majesté : this is my issue indeed :) I emailed them, they said it is not possible to disable the shipment section, so the only solution I guess is to inform the customer (in the website) to not change address in alert pay.

Comment: @AP Dev I've been told I can pass the shipping address using "apc" variables. I'm currently passing the shipping address to apc_3 , however I dunno how to set this on server side (Alertpay.com)